# Regular expression for match just words without special chars

Tags: c#, regex

How to match only the word without matching anything else using regex
considering that the word isn't a constant it changes for example it might be:

```
|-->    word    <--|  
|-->    game    <--|  
|-->    play    <--|  
etc ...
Match match = Regex.Match(packet.Payload, @"|-->(/\b([a-z]+)\b/)    <--|",
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (match.Success)
{
 string capture = match.Groups[1].Value;
 tcp.SendGroupTextMessage(targetId, capture);
}
```

these are the lines i'm currently using which works with some other forms so the only hinder is matching the regex to just the word and converting it into string to resend it
what i tried so far : `(\b([a-z]+)\b)`

```
(/\b([a-z]+)\b/)
(\w+)
```

Comment: Highly depends on your other requirements, border-cases, etc. But basically its a simple "literal match" + wildcard of your choice* + "literal match".

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: @ThomasAyoub Did you mean to remove the `|-->` symbols? I was under the impression that they were integral to OPs question as those were what he wanted to filter out.

Comment: @Equalsk i don't know why the |--> and  <--| got removed as the question was all about getting rid of these and just matching the word ,weird :/

Comment: I've rolled it back to your original context.

Comment: @mircato Jeah, that edit was counter-productive, it's been rolled back to your original question. You should format it properly so people don't think you just couldn't find the "bold" button. ;)

Comment: @Equalsk my bad, I though OP wasn't aware of mardown formatting.

Comment: @mircato: I suppose all you need is `Regex.Match(packet.Payload, @"\|-->\s+(\p{L}+)\s+<--\|")` and the `.Groups[1].Value` will hold what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone, I found the solution:
`@"\|-->(.*)<--|"`

Comment: Your capturing group now contains *anything* between `|-->` amd `<--`, OR an empty match because you did not escape the second `|`.

Comment: it captures just the word between |--> and <--|

Answer (score 0):

Based on the examples you've given you can just match on a word character:

```
// Create regex to match whole word
var regex = new Regex(@"\w+");

// Test cases
Console.WriteLine(regex.Match("|-->    word    <--|").ToString());
Console.WriteLine(regex.Match("|-->    game    <--|").ToString());
Console.WriteLine(regex.Match("|-->    play    <--|").ToString());
```

Output:

> word
>   game
>   play

Alternatively you don't need Regex, `.Replace()` and `.Trim()` also work:

```
"|--> word <--|".Replace("|-->","").Replace("<--|", "").Trim();
```

Output:

> word

Comment: i want my script to parse the group messages payload to find the same layout as |-->    word    <--| and then take just the word and resend it to the group so i got to use the if match.success statement which means trimming will be of no use

Comment: Call me crazy, maybe you could have put that information in the question...

Comment: sorry it's my first question in SOF :X i can't even send the code lines in code format it's messed up